# How do I use Membership Provider with Angular.js and ASP.Net MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am really new to the Angular.js and I want to create a new project with Angular.JS with ASP.Net MVC4. I am really confused with how to use Angular.JS with MVC 4 membership provider together to perform user authentication and authorization.

Are there any example projects I can look to get some ideas how to start?

Comment: What are the results you have right now, what exactly are you trying to achieve?  There are so many routes that could be taken from your question, it's not particularly that useful.  Give us a situation (default project template for instance) and narrow down the scope of this question by telling us what you think you'd like to see happen when you perform certain actions.

Comment: I give it benefit of doubt considering his question is specific to authentication and authorization together with a Angular.JS apps in MVC 4. Edited the question to be a bit clearer about this.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Have you done with this project i mean any solution?.

Answer (score 3):

There are some examples in [this cookbook to integrate Angular.JS into MVC project](https://github.com/Wintellect/Angular-MVC-Cookbook). There is also this [video tutorial provided by Dan Wahlin](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2013/04/12/video-tutorial-angularjs-fundamentals-in-60-ish-minutes.aspx) about the same.

Regarding authentication and authorization in Angular.JS, there is [this Starter project that uses Angular and Breeze and has a log-in implemented](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/breezeangular-template). So you might want to check out the code from that starter project to get going. You can look through the code and follow the discussion of this starter project in a [longer blog post](http://www.breezejs.com/ng-spa-template?utm_source=ms-spa).

Comment: Hi Spoike Thanks for the response. I looked at the breeze.js and angular.js. It is not exactly what I am looking for. I don't want razor mixed with html. I want the project only have html + angular + mvc webapi.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for the sake of completeness here's a tutorial of implementing login using Microsoft Identity Provider using WinApi and angular: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/