# how to create Login module using Membership provider in asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-membership

I am create small demo in AngularJs with mvc. i want create login module in demo using membership asp.net c#.but i am not aware with membership provider so any one help and know how to use memebrship provider and create login module with it.

Comment: Duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280304/getting-data-from-asp-net-mvc-membership-provider-with-angularjs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16734317/how-do-i-use-membership-provider-with-angular-js-and-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create login using membership in mvc 5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42486609/how-to-create-login-using-membership-in-mvc-5) - which while asked later, has more information in it